# CakePHP Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Cookie [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804]

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Cookie [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804]

I use `if ($this->Cookie->read('userId') != null)` in AppController and it gives me error above. Why?

Comment: How does it give you an error on `View` when your running that code in a controller?

Comment: your above statement would be better as `if (!$this->Cookie->read('userId'))` - but anyway: you use the cookie component in the view somehow. which doesnt make sense of course. try to find that piece of code and move it to the controller level.

Comment: That error would only be displayed in the view, not the controller, therefore, I think it's safe to say that the problem is that the `$this->Cookie->read()` is inside the view (`.ctp` file). CakePHP's CookieComponent cannot be used inside a view. If you need to read cookies in your view, either use `$this->set('name', $this->Cookie->read('value'));` in your controller or use the `$_COOKIE` variable in your view (unconventional as per CakePHP's coding standards).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add this to the controller:

```
var $components = array('Cookie');
```

Comment: Well, jeremyharris has a good point above. Why are you getting an error in the view? Can you post a little more code from the controller?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using the Cookie component in the CTP file